# How to transform PIL.Image object to buffer string?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stringio

```
sbuf = StringIO()
sbuf.write(decoded_file)
pimg = Image.open(sbuf)

print pimg.size

cimage = StringIO()
pimg.seek(0)
pimg.save(cimage,'jpeg')
contents = cimage.getvalue()
if contents == decoded_file:
   print '1------->> ok!'
```

'decoded_file' is a image buffer string.I want to transform the PIL.Image object 'pimg' to 'contents',and 'contents' should equal to 'decoded_file'.

Comment: Why do you expect `contents` to equal `decoded_file`? Is `decoded_file` a JPEG file created by PIL using the default `quality` & `optimize` parameters? If not, you're unlikely to get an exact match. BTW, you really should be using `BytesIO` for binary data, not `StringIO`. It might work ok in Python 2, but it won't in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, but 'decoded_file' is a normal picture data string.I want to pick the PIL.Image object to do some image deals.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "normal picture data string"? What format is this image data in? It would help if you include a small example in your question. And what does "image deals" mean?